# what up with Catalina password change?

Tags: macos, catalina, security, password

weird stuff. I went to user preferences and changed my simple user password for login, system preferences, etc to a longer one due to the fact that im bringing in the laptop, 2019 16" in for keyboard issues.  After the change, I logged out then back in to test the pw.  it worked.  shut computer down.  about hr later I needed to get a doc I forgot.  In trying to login the computer wouldn't accept the pw.  I had tested it and written it down - no good.  Called apple and they walked me through sys recovery command line to do an account add and pw change.  wouldn't work.  then a command line reset and the system said it took - I changed it back to a simple pw - 5 letter one.  logged out and then tried to log in w/ the new pw and it would not work.  I then tried the one wouldn't work, the reason for calling apple - and it worked!  But only for log in.  Prefrences pw was still the 14 letter old one.  Had to do ANOTHER reset and finally ok.  But now for some reason my computer has a new name - see "test's" name in attachment.  For some reason the computer took the test account name we created during troubleshooting to fix pw issue - what's up w/that?  What s with all the password issues?  Why would it let me change the pw then not work?  Anyone have any ideas or have this issue?  Finally, if id known that it would protect the data by changing the pw, I wouldn't have bothered.  Seems anyone can get into the computer...
[image: test name]

Comment: Is it possible you now have two user accounts: wmmbp and test, and that you've been using the wrong password for the wrong account?
Also, you shouldn't need to change the password if taking it in to repair. They'll wipe the disk if they need to, otherwise they won't touch it.

Comment: Nope. The apple CS had me create the test account to access the system and It has since been deleted. For some reason my device is now renamed “test”. 

What’s with the system not taking my new verified password?  And then Only after the 2nd change taking in one place and not the other?  This is messed up.

Comment: You can fix the name in System Preferences > Sharing.